# stack overflow error in C++ program

Tags: c++, class, visual-c++, pointers

So i have this complex class , and i want to have an 2d array of complex numbers this is part of the code not all the code

```
class Complex {
public:
    /* construction/destruction */
    Complex(double r, double i)     { this->r = r; this->i = i; }
    Complex()                       { r=0.0; i=0.0; }
    ~Complex()                      { r=0.0; i=0.0; }
        /* operations */
    Complex operator+(Complex &c)   { return Complex( r+c.r, i+c.i ); }
        double r, i;
};

int main()
{
const int HEIGHT = 256;
const int WIDTH = 256;
Complex G[HEIGHT][WIDTH];
}
```

so the line Complex G[HEIGHT][WIDTH]; is the line that causes the problem , any idea why ?

Comment: Assuming an 8 byte double, that's 1MB of stack storage for `G` alone, which is typically the overall limit.

Comment: Because you're overflowing the stack with 65536 `Complex` objects. It's really not a ... complex ... thing to understand.

Comment: It is better not to allocate large arrays on the stack - use `malloc` - and maybe create an access function as part of the class in order to keep the indexing simple.

Comment: @Floris, s/`malloc`/`vector`/.

Comment: Try static. This puts it into the static data area and avoids wasting precious stack... unlike malloc the compiler still knows where it is at compile time :)

Comment: @chris - thanks. Mixing my languages...

Answer (score 8):

Visual studio defaults to 1MB stack size, it looks like:

```
Complex G[HEIGHT][WIDTH];
```

will be just about 1MB, you can modify this using [/F](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdkhxaks%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and the document says (*emphasis mine*):

> **Without this option the stack size defaults to 1 MB**. The number argument can be in decimal or C-language notation. The argument can range from 1 to the maximum stack size accepted by the linker. The linker rounds up the specified value to the nearest 4 bytes. The space between /F and numberis optional.

The most obvious alternative would be to use dynamic memory allocation via *new* or [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

*Visual Studio* as far as I know actually has [one of the smaller default](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/exact/core/doc/stackOverflow.txt) stack sizes:

```
platform    default size       
=====================================
SunOS/Solaris  8192K bytes
Linux          8192K bytes
Windows        1024K bytes
cygwin         2048K bytes
Mac OS X       8192K bytes
```

Answer (score 1):

> Any idea why?

Some compilers default the stack size to 1MB. You are allocating 65536 `Complex` objects that occupies 2 * `sizeof(double)` memory each. Assuming `double` to be 8 bytes (this information is implementation defined) you are effectively trying to allocate 16 * 65536 bytes (without considering possible paddings), which are  1048576 bytes, that causes the overflow.

An alternative is using dynamic allocation with a wrapper, that simulates a bi-dimensional array indexing, along the lines of this one:

```
template<std::size_t A, std::size_t B>
class G {
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Complex[]> mem;
public:
    G() : mem(new Complex[A * B]) {}
    Complex& operator()(std::size_t a, std::size_t b) {
        return mem[a * B + b];
    }
    Complex  operator()(std::size_t a, std::size_t b) const {
        return mem[a * B + b];
    }
};
```

Then you program simply becomes:

```
int main(int, char*[]) {
    G<256, 256> g;
    g(0, 0) = ...;
}
```

Of course you can generalize your wrapper `G` for a generic type with templates, but that's outside the scope of this answer.

---

On a side note, you destructor:

```
~Complex() { r=0.0; i=0.0; }
```

is useless. Don't re-initialize memory that will be destroyed anyway when it leaves the scope.