# Strange runtime exception in C++

Tags: c++, runtime

I reduced my program to an extremely short form and the exception still shows up. What is going on?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int array[5000000];
    int variable = 0;  // here, EXC_BAD_ACCESS
    return 0;
}
```

Is 5.000.000 elements of int too much? That's just 4 bytes * 50 millions = under 20 MB. What the...? :P

Comment: What platform are you on?  First guess would be a stack limit issue.

Comment: Typical stack size is [pretty small](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20234082/1708801)

Comment: Not that strange. You try to allocate 20 megabytes on the stack, what do you think happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the other answer suggested, you are more than likely hitting the stack limit.  A solution to this is to use a container such as `std::vector`.

```
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> array(5000000);
    array[100] = 49;  // use [] just like an array
    int variable = 0;  
    return 0;
}
```

This now shouldn't give you a runtime error.

Also, I don't recommend calling your variable `array`, since there already is a `std::array` class.  Right now it doesn't hurt you, but you never know when or if a future coding change will use the `std::array` class.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are running into stack limit issues on the Mac.  Your large array is allocated on the stack so when you try to run your program you exceed the (some what small) default stack limit on OS X.

https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/qa/qa1419/_index.html